# Laravel: calling controller method from another location

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel app I have the following controller that takes the instance of Elastic search as a first parameter and then another variable:

```
use Elasticsearch\Client;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AngularController extends Controller {
    public function selectRandom(Client $es, $numRows) {
        # ...search params here
        $results = $es->search($searchParams);
        return $results;
    }
}
```

I need to call the method of the controller above from another controller, I do it like this:

```
class HomeCtrl extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $featured = new AngularController();

        return $featured->selectRandom(12);
    }

}
```

I get the following error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\AngularController::selectRandom() must be an
>   instance of Elasticsearch\Client, integer given

I'm not well versed in OOP. Do I call it incorrectly? Because I though the method I call would take instance that is injected in controller, not from where I call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **When you are calling a method from your Controller to another**
>   **Controller that means you are doing wrong. For this purpose you should**
>   **use service.**

Create a class in app\Services Utility.php

```
use Elasticsearch\Client;

class Utility {

    public function selectRandom(Client $es, $numRows) {
        # ...search params here
        $results = $es->search($searchParams);
        return $results;
    }
}
```

> **and just inject this class to your controller**

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a clean method to call classes from controllers. I did as you wrote, but if I inject the instance as a parameter in the class the same error occurs, when I call the method of this Utility class from my controller as it expects Elasticsearch instance to be passed when I call this `selectRandom` method even though I'd this instance injected in the class itself. So I guess I'll have to instantiate Elasticsearch inside the class as another answer suggested. Or there's another solution for this?

Comment: @dmit I just wrote a guide but I am not sure you are passing **`$numRows`** parameter but you didn't used it also you are using **`$searchParams`** variable which is not initialized from anywhere. That's may be causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

In your AngularController class selectRandom method first parameter is a class instance second one is number,that's why you get this error.If you want to access this method using object form another controller you need to set first parameter of this object and second one is your id.Another solution is here

some modify in selectRandom method

```
public function selectRandom($numRows) {
    # ...search params here
    $es = new Client();
    $results = $es->search($searchParams);
    return $results;
}
```

Then you use this function

```
public function index() {

    $featured = new AngularController();

    return $featured->selectRandom(12);
}
```